# NSCalendarUnit: is NSCalendarUnitNanosecond a valid enum value for NSCalendarUnit or not?

Tags: ios, xcode, enums

I have a switch/case section of code in an iOS project that checks a variable of type NSCalendarUnit. At first, Xcode 5.0.2 gives a warning about not including some of the enum values in switch statements. So I added the rest of them, except NSCalendarUnitNanosecond, which Xcode indicates is not available in for iOS, and even puts a red strikethrough line through it when showing the auto-completion selections. Yet, Xcode 5.0.2 is still giving me the warning

> Enumeration value 'NSCalendarUnitNanosecond' not handled in switch

So is it valid for iOS or not?

(it's part of Mac OS X, e.g., https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/Foundation.htm

As a side note, it's interesting that the Apple docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCalendar_Class/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003626-RH1-SW1 are out of date, being last updated in 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When preprocessing the source file, one can see that the definition of `NSCalendarUnit`
expands on iOS to

```
enum NSCalendarUnit : NSUInteger {
// ...
NSCalendarUnitNanosecond __attribute__((availability(ios,unavailable))) = (1 << 15),
// ...
}
```

which means that `NSCalendarUnitNanosecond` is *not available* on iOS.

But it seems that the compiler does not honor the availability attribute correctly
when checking the `switch` statement.

This can easily be reproduced with the following example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3 UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE
};

enum MyEnum e = 0;
switch (e) {
    case Enum1:
    case Enum2:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

also produces a "Enumeration value  not handled in switch" warning when compiling with
`-Weverything`. This seems to be a compiler bug.

Of course you can suppress the warning locally with

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum"

// switch-statement

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was probably a compiler bug, and its good to see you confirm it, plus also suggest how to suppress the warning.